# how to remember the radio selection?

Tags: php, jquery

after I post it use ajax,the value of radio disappear,but I want the radio part to remember the selection.  I need the page to remember the radio button selections when I leaves and returns. Would this require database? If so, how do i implement it? I try to add the select =selected ,but it do not help.

```
<input value="<?php echo $key; $key++;?>" type="radio" class="radioOrCheck" name="answer<?php echo $num_select;?>"
                                    id="0_answer_<?php echo $num_select;?>_option_<?php echo $key;?>"
```

below it is the full code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/iconfont.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    <style>
    .hasBeenAnswer {
        background: #5d9cec;
        color:#fff;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
    
    </p>
        <div class="main">
            <!--nr start-->
            <div class="test_main">
                <div class="nr_left">
                    <div class="test">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <div class="test_title">
                            <!--
                                <p class="test_time">
                                    <i class="icon iconfont">&#xe6fb;</i><b class="alt-1">01:40</b>
                                </p>-->
                                <font><?php echo "<input type='button' name='test_jiaojuan' value='sub' onClick='getinput($ans_json,$id_json)'>";?>
    </font>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                                <div class="test_content">
                                    <div class="test_content_title">
                                        <h2>word</h2>
                                        <p>
                                            <span>has</span><i class="content_lit"><?php echo $cnt_sel;?></i><span>title</span><span>sum</span><i class="content_fs"><?php echo $cnt_sel*10;?></i><span>min</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="test_content_nr">
                                    <ul>
                                        
                                        <!--begin select-->
    <?php
    foreach($results as $temp){
        $sql_2="SELECT `description`,`input`,`select_id` FROM `select` WHERE `select_id`=?";
        $res_2=pdo_query($sql_2,$temp[0]);
        $row = $res_2[0];
        ?>
    <li id="qu_0_<?php echo $num_select;?>">
        <div class="test_content_nr_tt">
            <i><?php echo $num_select;?></i><font>
            <p>
            <?php
                echo $row[0];
            ?>
            </p>
            </font>
        </div>
    
        <div class="test_content_nr_main">
            <ul>
            
                    <?php
                    if ($row[1]) {
                        $arr = rtrim($row[1],"<br />");
                        $arr = explode('<br />', $arr); 
                        foreach($arr as $key => $a){
                        
                    ?>
                    <li class="option">
                    <input value="<?php echo $key; $key++;?>" type="radio" class="radioOrCheck" name="answer<?php echo $num_select;?>"
                                id="0_answer_<?php echo $num_select;?>_option_<?php echo $key;?>"
                            />
                        <label for="0_answer_<?php echo $num_select;?>_option_<?php echo $key;?>">
                            <p class="ue" style="display: inline;"><?php echo strip_tags($a,"<img>");//echo trim($a); ?></p>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    
                    }
                    } 
                if ($row['hint']) {
                    ?><h4><?php echo $MSG_HINT;?></h4><?php
                    echo $row['hint'];
                }
                    ?>
            </ul>
            </br></br>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php
    $num_select=$num_select+1;
    }
    ?>
    <p>
    <?php
    
    ?>
    </p>
    <!--end select-->
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            
                        </form>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                <div class="nr_right">
                    <div class="nr_rt_main">
                        <div class="rt_nr1">
                            <div class="rt_nr1_title">
                                <h1>
                                    <i class="icon iconfont">&#xe692;</i>answer
                                </h1>
                        <!--        <p class="test_time">
                                    <i class="icon iconfont">&#xe6fb;</i><b class="alt-1">01:40</b>
                                </p>-->
                            </div>
                            
                                <div class="rt_content">
                                    <div class="rt_content_tt">
                                        <h2>chose</h2>
                                        <p>
                                            <span>sum</span><i class="content_lit"><?php echo $cnt_sel;?></i><span>answer</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rt_content_nr answerSheet">
                                        <ul>
    
                                            <?php
                                                $temp=1;
                                                for($temp=1;$temp<=$cnt_sel;$temp++){
                                                    ?>
                                                    
                                            <li><a href="#qu_0_<?php echo $temp;?>"><?php echo $temp;?></a></li>        
                                                    
                                                    
                                            <?php   
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--nr end-->
            <div class="foot"></div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    
        <script src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
        <script>
            
            $(function() {
                $('li.option label').click(function() {
                debugger;
                    var examId = $(this).closest('.test_content_nr_main').closest('li').attr('id'); 
                    var cardLi = $('a[href=#' + examId + ']'); 
                    
                    if(!cardLi.hasClass('hasBeenAnswer')){
                        cardLi.addClass('hasBeenAnswer');
                    }
                });
            });
            $(function() {
                $('li.option').click(function() {
                debugger;
                    var examId = $(this).closest('.test_content_nr_main').closest('li').attr('id'); 
                    var cardLi = $('a[href=#' + examId + ']'); 
                    if(!cardLi.hasClass('hasBeenAnswer')){
                        cardLi.addClass('hasBeenAnswer');
                    }
                    
                });
            });
        /*window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
        var msg = '';
        msg +='do not like?\n';
        //msg += '';
        return msg;
    };*/
        function getinput(ans_json,results_json) {
        var sum=<?php echo $cnt_sel;?>;
        var blank_cnt=0;
        var well_cnt=0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {
            var radio_name = new String("answer" + i.toString());
            var ans_s = $('input:radio[name=' + radio_name + ']:checked').val();
            if(!(ans_s)){
                blank_cnt++;
        }}
          //var json = getjson();
          var msg = "ok";
          if (confirm(msg) == true) {
            var radio = new Array();
            for (var i = 1; i <= <?php echo $cnt_sel;?>; i++) {
            var radio_name = new String("answer" + i.toString());
            var ans_s = $('input:radio[name=' + radio_name + ']:checked').val();
            if(!(ans_s)){
                ans_s=-1;
                }
            var judge=0;
            var answer_true= parseInt(ans_json[i-1]);
            var id_true=parseInt(results_json[i-1]);
            if(ans_s == answer_true){
                judge=1;
            }
        
            $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "select_ajax.php",
               data: {
                   select_id: id_true,
                   contest_id:<?php echo $cid;?>,
                   result:judge
               },
               success: function(msg){
                   well_cnt++;
               }
            });
          }
            if(well_cnt==5){
                alert('success');
            }
            setTimeout(function (){
             window.location.href = "contest.php?cid="+<?php echo $cid;?>;
    }, 1000);
    
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you could use `localStorage` on a per-user basis to remember these settings. A cookie also might be another option - but the browser should have support for webSQL, IndexedDB too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by storing your radio button value in javascript localStorage and then set that localStorage value to your radio button again.